# Support for Realtek8111e

Tags: 11.10, drivers, realtek

Putting Realtek 8111e support into 11.10 requires an unreasonable amount of work if one only wants a 'Live' CD to evaluate Ubuntu.  Since Linux is worthless without the Internet, I can't even evaluate it until 8111e suport is included.

Comment: You might want to put some info on what you've tried so others can see what you've done. Also, which laptop are you running this card on?

Comment: This isn't really a constructive question; however, given the generally great quality of the answer I'm going to keep this around.

Answer (score 3):

Linux is worthless without internet? At least Ubuntu comes with lots of useful applications by default, unlike some other operating systems you may have heard of. As with Windows, for example, drivers can be provided on a CD that comes with the product. You would then double-click the .deb-file, be provided with a graphical wizard and install the driver, just like in any other operating system. Or you can download the driver yourself and copy it the old fashioned way, just like you would do in Windows if you had lost the driver CD. In other words, this has nothing to do with Linux or Windows, but is about poor customer service.

Drivers are the hardware manufacturers job, though Linux does provide drivers even for some of the least customer friendly manufacturers. If your hardware manufacturer refuses to provide you with a driver CD, and will not let drivers be built into the operating system, then that's bad customer service and should be remembered the next time you purchase hardware.

Comment: Too bad though it seems often like few, if any, hardware manufacturers really give much thought to Linux. You can say "I learned my lesson here, I'm buying a competitor's product", but the sad truth I feel is that *none* of them really provide decent and consistent customer service, at least not on the same level as Windows support. This probably will not be resolved until [bug 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1) is fixed.

Comment: And this is a major reason why Ubuntu is important. If they support Ubuntu, they support everyone. But it is important that it's easy. We must push Ubuntu to the level of Windows in all situations. Even those that do support "Linux", require you to log in as root in order to run the installer. Horrible. Linux is for hobbyists. Ubuntu and Android is for the masses.